# date comparison in unix and identify the earlier one

Tags: unix, sunos

I have two dates to compare and find out the earlier one. ( using SunOS 5.10)

date1='01May2014'
  date2='03Apr2014'

I need to determine the earlier date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used sql to solve since i dont find answer into unix.

select least((select to_date('01May2014','DDMONYYYY')from dual ),
(select to_date('01Apr2014','DDMONYYYY') from dual )) from dual;

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
date --date='01May2014' +"%Y%m%d"
date --date='03Apr2014' +"%Y%m%d"
```

Then you can sort numerically.

```
D1='01May2014'
D2='03Apr2014'

for D in $D1 $D2
do
    date --date=$D +"%Y%m%d"
done | sort | head -1
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: 20141201 for 01May2014

Comment: That's not parsing at all then, as that's today's date. Probably a different version of the `date` command. More involved solution needed unfortunately. How do you get on with Perl? :)